# Restrict access to CiviCRM home

Tags: civievent, drupal, permissions

I am running CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Drupal 7.

I am using the "Event Calendar" extension to expose a calendar view. The extension works well, with one problem: it only displays the calendar to users with the "Access CiviCRM" permission.

I have had to enable this for anonymous users, which isn't ideal to begin with, but I can manage it by restricting their access to everything else. However, as a result, they can access the CiviCRM Home and Dashboard (despite not having permission to it in Drupal permissions). The Dashboard shows every available dashlet with a bit old "ACCESS DENIED" under it. I'd rather avoid this altogether, and get them to an Access Denied page if they try to access CiviCRM home. Is this possible?

Comment: We've got part of an old custom Drupal module that whitelists certain users by Drupal role to only be able to access certain pages, otherwise they get redirected. It was used for the previous version of our members' portal until last year. But looking at what permission the extension checks for is the better solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a closer look at the event calendar extension and check which permission exactly it needs (something more specific like "CiviEvent: view event info" might work) - if that's not the case, I would file an issue with that extension as it's probably a bug. Ask the extension author to change the permission check to "CiviEvent: view event info".

Comment: And if they don't respond, ask your friendly neighbourhood freelancer to do it for you :)

Comment: I have tried this! And filed the bug... and I'm the YFNF in question, but new to CiviCRM so not quite sure where permission hooks sit yet. Will find it though.

Answer (score 2):

I published an example View for a [CiviEvent calendar](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/simple-view-showing-civi-events-calendar). It may be useful to you as a way around the issue. Note the need for [CiviCRM Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module

Screenshots per Jon's request

Add view from template [image]

Views displays [image]

Comment: Intriguing!  Do you have a screenshot available you can add, here or on the blog?

Comment: not sure which you were wanting. added a couple

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty good but it doesn't seem to display multi-day events short of adding start and end date fields to the display - other than on whichever date (end or start) selected. I found a way to do this on the Drupal site using a number of modules, but its a little beyond me. Hoping the existing CIVICRM extension is updated!