# Event Calendar does not show up on civi 4.7.7

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I'm trying to use the extension Event Calendar (developer branch as advised here: [Problem with Event Calendar extension after upgrade to 4.7.3](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10512/problem-with-event-calendar-extension-after-upgrade-to-4-7-3)) however the Calendar does not show up, the "Event Calendar Settings" is fine.
The master branch works fine on 4.6.11. Has anyone been using it on 4.7.x?
The CMS is Wordpress.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but reinstalled the extension and everything came back.